# num+den-1/num largest unit factor

Tags: math, fractions

If w have a factor and we want to get the largest unit factor less than it, Why we use this equation to get the least denominator:
(numerator+denominator-1/numerator) ?
I don't understand it

Comment: Because you do not use this wrong formula. Instead you use `(numerator+denominator-1)/denominator`.

Comment: Sorry I've edited it, but still don't understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(den+num-1) / num = (den - 1)/num + 1
```

in integer division gives the next largest integer to the ratio `den/num`. Note that when this ratio is already an integer, i.e., `den` is an integer multiple of `num`, then the formula returns exactly this integer.

That is, this formula is the (always exact) integer variant of the floating point formula

```
fceil(den/(double)num)
```